# How can I give a table that is inside of a TD 100% height i.e full height of the TD

Tags: html, html-table

This is how my table looks like. When I try to give the table 100% height but it doesn't work.

I want the TD that contains "xxx" to have 100% height i.e. the height of the parent TD.

```
</tr>

    <tr align="left">
        <td valign="top">
            <table style="height:100%" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span title="Toggle between full screen and frames." id="showHideText"  onclick="showHideFrames();" 
                                class="buttonLabel" style="cursor:pointer; font-size:65%; font-weight:bold;">
                            Hide Frames
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="bottom" >
                        xxx
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
```

Comment: The fact that you have a nested table indicates a very strong problem with your code. Google "No tables for layout".

Comment: There are several layout mechanics that can't be established without tables. Using nested tables is no sign of bad code, just of insufficent CSS standards capabilities. Plus, many layouts are still just easier and more cross browser reliable to do with tables, even if there are many counter examples around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
<table>
        <tr align="left" style="height: 1000px">
            <td valign="top">
                <table style="height: 100%" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span title="Toggle between full screen and frames." id="showHideText" onclick="showHideFrames();"
                                class="buttonLabel" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 65%; font-weight: bold;">
                                Hide Frames </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="bottom" style="height: 1000px">
                            xxx
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the CSS height property:

```
style="height:100%;"
```